# Is it possible to Plot Damping Characteristic of a Gas Strut using Universal Tensile Machine(UTM)?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

My aim is to use UTM to plot a Force vs Displacement plot which would demonstrate the damping characteristic of the gas strut. There is one [existing research](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5034562) related to what I'm trying to achieve which gives me hope.

I'm trying to use a United UTM which comes with the DATUM 3.0 software. It already has a program template for a compression cycle but not for the tension cycle. Right now I'm trying to edit the program by adding the other half of the cycle to the program. Then I'll set multiple cycles of compression and tension. The curve is plotting correctly for the compression but the tension cycle is just a straight vertical line.

I'm aware that testing damping characteristics require shaker test but the company I'm working for doesn't have the budget for it.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to use UTM to develop damping characteristic of the strut?
2. I'm working with very old and insufficient documentation here so I was wondering, whether there are some existing standards or test methods to evaluate gas struts without using the shaker test?

Comment: I had an MTS unit with an oven/chiller that spanned the nip. Just guessing, but I would think the response of the fluid in the strut may be modulated by temperature. For your consideration... damper use with large thermal swings may produce inconsistent results where actuation response is critical (thinking of safety). I would also think the manufacturer might have this data (they might have to dig for it, but it is probably there).

Comment: @JimClark Thanks for sharing that! The manufacturer has supplied the data but my company wants to validate their data or do some additional testing. What do you think is there a way to do some DIY experiment to test gas struts? And are there any standards on that matter?

Comment: You need to find out what extra "data" your company wants. Remember that your max and min stroke are your limits on actuation. Maybe work within 90-95% of the entire stroke envelope. You could suggest that you will run multiple increasing stroke velocities and measure the load response, to obain a family of curves. One family for extension and one for compression. But if that is not what they wanted,then you have wasted their money.